# running code in another function's scope (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, function, scope, eval

So I'm working on a sort of JavaScript framework, just some utility things for myself to use in future projects, and I want to make a data binding system.

The first method I used was objects, and the code would just loop through the specified html element and look for occurences of `{{key}}` in the markup and then look for that key in the object and replace it that way in the HTML.

For example, if you had `<div>{{name}} is a cool guy</div>` in the HTML and had `{name:"joseph"}` in the JS then the final product would be displayed on screen as 'joseph is a cool guy'.

However, I decided later to change my method and instead the framework would except a function. So instead of `{name:"joseph"}` you would give it `function(){ var name = "joseph" }`.

This obviously looks better and gives a lot better functionality.

I changed the processing function so instead of looking for the key/value pair to replace the `{{key}}`, it just uses eval on the variable to gets its value.

---

My problem lies here: How do I run my search/replace code INSIDE the scope of the function the user passes.

If the user defines variables within that function, their values will not be available anywhere else due to scope issues.

I've tried using `Function.toString()` to actually modify the source code of the function, but nothing's working and it's all very complicated.
(The issues are not due to the actual solution, I think that `Function.toString()` might work, but due to my implementation. I keep getting errors)

So... What is the best way to run arbitrary code in the scope of another function?

Critera:

1. Obviously, I can't modify the function because the user is passing it in. (you can't just tell me to add the search/replace code to the bottom of the function)
2. The variables must stay in the local scope of the function. (no cheating by using `window.name = "joseph"` or anything)

I am also aware of how terrible `eval` is so any suggestions as to get it to work are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

---

Code:

```
function process(html) {
        var vars = html.match( /({{)[^{}]*(}})/g )
        // vars = ['{{variable}}', '{{anotherVariable}}']
        var names = vars.map( function(x){ return x.replace("{{", "").replace("}}", "") } )
        // names = ['variable', 'anotherVariable]

        obj = {}

        for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            obj[names[i]] = eval(names[i])
        }

        for (var p in obj) {
            html = html.replace(new RegExp('{{'+p+'}}','g'), obj[p]);
        }

        return html
}
```

Comment: "*This obviously looks better and gives a lot better functionality.*" - please explain. As your question shows, it severely lacks functionality.

Comment: "*What is the best way to run arbitrary code in the scope of another function?*" - there is no way at all, it's impossible.

Comment: An object just gives keys that lead to values, whereas a function gives code that can actually be run. For example, you should be able to have for loops and add elements to the document when the function is run, as well as declare variables. An object only gives you the capability to define variables.

Comment: Then make a function that takes a key and returns a value if you need to dynamically create those things. But no, the loop would need to be part of your template language, not of the data that is passed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go back to your first method with the object, it's much better. You can still pass a function, but the function should return an object:

```
function () {
    return { name: 'joseph' }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Pretty obvious, but I never though about just having the function return an object.